# Print like count without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a like/unlike post on my website, and when I click the like button I would like the value of check2 to show beside like without me having to refresh the page to see it. Currently I'll click like and it inserts the data but only shows on a page refresh. I'm hopeless with this kind of stuff.

Here is the code in the order it executes.

Thanks for any help.

POST LIKE

```
echo "<div class='stream_option'><a id='likecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.id);\">";
if($checklikes>0){
echo "Unlike";
}else{
echo "Like";
}
echo "</a> ";
$check2 = user_core::print_like_count($streamitem_data['streamitem_id']);
if($check2>0){
echo "(".$check2.")";
}
```

Ajax Function

```
function likestatus(postid,contextid){
var obj = document.getElementById(contextid);
if(obj.innerHTML=="Like"){
obj.innerHTML="Unlike";
}else{
obj.innerHTML="Like";
}
$.post("../include/like_do.php", { streamitem_id: postid} );
}
```

LIKE_DO

```
$check = user_core::check_liked($_SESSION['id'],$_POST['streamitem_id'],1);

user_core::do_like($_SESSION['id'],$_POST['streamitem_id'],1);

    if($check==0){
    ?>
    <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <?php
    }
}
else{
echo "<script>alert('Error liking post');</script>";
}
?>
```

USER_CORE

```
 function check_liked($id,$streamid,$value){

            $check      =   "SELECT feedback_id FROM streamdata_feedback WHERE feedback_streamid=$streamid AND feedback_userid=$id AND feedback_rating=$value";
            $check1     =    mysql_query($check);
            $check2     =    mysql_num_rows($check1);
        return $check2;
        }

        function print_like_count($streamid){
                $check      =   "SELECT feedback_id FROM streamdata_feedback WHERE feedback_streamid=$streamid AND feedback_rating=1";
                $check1     =    mysql_query($check);
                $check2     =    mysql_num_rows($check1);
                if($check2>0){
                echo "(".$check2.")";
                }
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't show the like count unless you refresh the page. I would just like it to show once clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an AJAX submission using DHTML to change the value of the likes.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(".likeButton").click(function() {
        $.post("likeProcessor.php", {
            id: $(this).attr('id')
        }, function(data) {
            $("#likeIndicator" + $(this).attr('id')).html(data);
        });
</script>
```

Then your likeProcessor script will simply return the number of likes for that item.

**NOTE:** This is pseudo-code to give you an idea of what needs to happen. For further info on jQuery and Ajax, RTM at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp respectively.

Comment: @dave you **MUST** include the success callback for it to update anything on your page.

Comment: Cheer Matt, will give it ago. And yes, I noticed the missing success. Will add that into it. Thank you. :)

Comment: The id: $(this).attr('id') Do I need to change this?

Comment: @dave id will be POSTed to likeProcessor.php. It can be whatever you need it to be, but `$(this).attr('id)` will return the value of the id attribute of the "like" button which was clicked.

Comment: So in my case 'postid' and I add post id into the click function(postid) like so.. I don't really use Ajax, so in honesty, it goes over ones head. Trying to grasp it tho by reading around and asking straight forward questions, whilst trying to teach myself.

Comment: @dave You don't need to add a parameter to `.click(function() {...})` (not sure if that's what you were asking). As long as your postid is contained in the *id* attribute of the "Like" button then yes, replacing `id: $(this).attr('id')` with `postid: $(this).attr('id')` will work.

Comment: Then all you have to do is make your background script `echo` out the current number of likes for that particular item and the callback function (`function(data){...}`) will take care of everything else, as long as you have an element with an id of *likeIndicator[x]*.

Comment: Right the like is working. But still its not showing up the like within <div id='likeIndicator'></div> on my home.php page. Do I need to add something to my likeProcessor.php page?

Comment: @dave You have to have some sort of output (the number of likes is probably all you need).